# How to overwrite a line with carriage return, using a for-loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, carriage-return

I'm trying to print out  a string with the `end=\r` to send the cursor back to beginning of the line, and overwrite the printed string using a for loop

This is the code thus far I got :

```
import time

print("░░░░░░░░░░░░░", end='\r')
for i in ("SECRET"):
    print(i ,end='')
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Ideally, it should slowly overwrite some of the dotted pattern characters with characters from `"SECRET" every 0.3 seconds.

However, when run, the for loop instead iterates and prints characters on a single space, overwriting the characters it prints out itself, instead of advancing to the next available space, overwriting the dot pattern there and typing out the remaining characters in the string it iterates over

Removing the entire print statement associated with the dotted pattern characters allows the loop to function normally, printing out the string it iterates over properly, however, it is needed for the loop to print out the string and overwrite the dotted characters

Essentially, I want to overwrite some of the dotted pattern characters one by one using characters from the string the for loop iterates over, with the help of \r

I am on Ubuntu Studio

Comment: Add `flush=True` to `print(i, end='')`.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper I am using Ubuntu Studio

Comment: Very strange, are you using the standard Terminal without too many specialties in terms of `.bashrc` and other modifications?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper Are you referring to the IDE in which I run the code? If so, I'm using Thonny IDE

Answer (score 1):

Screen output is *line-buffered*.  This means that when you print something followed by a newline it appears on the screen immediately, but if you print something without a newline it might take a while to appear.

This is what's happening to you -- the output inside the for loop is not followed by a newline, so it doesn't appear onscreen immediately.

You can add `flush=True` to the print call to force the output to appear immediately instead of waiting:

```
print(i, end='', flush=True)
```

Comment: The for loop still continues to print the string its iterating on, on the same space character, even after adding flush=True?

Comment: Adding `flush=True` was the cause and the solution on Linux, but not to the problem described in the original question. On Linux nothing would appear until after the loop (and thus program exit and buffer flush)

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper I decided to test by removing time.sleep() entirely, and tested the code twice. Once without flush, once with flush in the code. Both work. It seems time.sleep() is the culprit but im not sure why its causing this issue.  I need time.sleep() in the output so I cant remove it either

Answer (score 0):

you can't overwrite characters in python.
you can, though, clear the whole screen by using `os.system('cls')` on windows or `os.system('clear')` on linux and unix.
here is the full code:

```
import time, os

output = '░░░░░░░░░░░░░'
for i in range(7):
    print(output)
    output = "SECRET"[:i]+output[i:]
    time.sleep(0.3)
    if os.name == 'nt': #on windows
       os.system("cls")
    else:
       os.system("clear") #not on windows
print(output)
```

also, this will only work when you are not running from the shell and if you want to see the full output, write `time.sleep(1)` at the end.

Comment: _you can't overwrite characters in python_ What?  Sure you can.  Printing a backspace character will move the cursor one space to the left, and printing a carriage return will move the cursor all the way to the left.  Once you do those things, you can then print new characters that will replace the existing characters on the line.

Comment: in my python shell, backspace prints a box and carriage return does nothing

Comment: For me, `print("aaa\b\b\bccc")` in the python shell ends up with `ccc` as the only displayed characters.  I'm not surprised carriage return does nothing, as the shell does its own line I/O handling.  Have you tried it from a standalone script?